# What does the water in the hallway represent in the Erased opening?

Tags: erased

Most of the shots in Erased its opening are references to events events or cryptic imagery like when Satoru's refers to himself as Grim Reaper that tries to put things back the way they were, but the more he acts the more other people involved suffer (see the last bit in episode 6).

[image: Grim Reaper]

However at around 37 seconds into the opening this shot of a large amount of water in the school shows up. I don't remember this happening in the anime.

[image: Water in the hallway]

What is the meaning of this shot? Does it bear a cryptic message to something in the show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SPOILERS:**

There's no objective answer that I've encountered, however this is my interpretation;

Literal: Satoru being drowned.

Figurative: Satoru's old life being "washed away" after nearly being drowned and losing his memory.